# Is this question on hold due to the subject as opposed to the lack of details?

Tags: discussion

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63671/title-of-a-movie-featuring-a-rape-scene-involving-the-main-characters-wife

It's pretty clear what the movie in question is, since it's a famous (notorious) film in cinema history.

Sam Peckinpah was a groundbreaking director, and his work is quite nuanced, so although Straw Dogs has elements of exploitation, that is not the purpose of the film, and the controversial nature of both the rape and violence in the film spurred dialogue on both subjects.

Answer (score 10):

It is a one-sentence two-liner. So yeah...whatever the subject, my first bet would be on utter and complete lack of details and effort of any kind. I say it again, and be it for 5 millionth time: **answerability is *not* quality nor effort nor details.**

It is a terrible question and in this form not the slightest of what an ID question is remotely supposed to be. It doesn't matter at all if you can answer that in a second and feel compelled to upvote it for exactly that reason. That is still *not* how ID quality and improving questions works and has never been.

Comment: Actually, as I mentioned in a comment, the inclusion of the wife's hometown and hunting trip are legit, key identifiers, as with the status of one of the rapists as the wife's ex-flame. That's three important plot points as identifiers.

Comment: With that said, I do recognize that this question will have emotional weight for many, and may be uncomfortable.  I've already been downvoted merely for having the temerity to answer. :)

Comment: Indeed, the uncomfortable topic of awful ID questions.

Comment: Again, I have to disagree.  Although poorly worded, the question included three key plot points that make it simple to distinguish this film from other films.

Comment: *"make it simple to distinguish this film from other films"* That's still not 'quality' or 'effort', though.

Comment: English may be a second language for the questioner based on the weird sentence construction.  I do feel I have to point out that not only do the 3 plot points make the film easy to distinguish, anyone with a grounding in the history of modern American cinema would be well aware of the film in question because of the controversy surrounding it.

Comment: @DukeZhou It's still a brief one-liner that lacks *all* the extraneous details mentioned [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) other than some plot points. Again, as the mods said many times, *it's not about recognizability*, and the fact that we might know the answer doesn't mean the *question* is up to standard. [**This**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55774/married-man-and-salesman-have-very-pleasant-conversation-after-marital-argument) is the kind of effort we're striving for in ID Qs.

Comment: (And as for your original question, no, I wouldn't VTC the question because of its subject unless it contained some malicious intent. But I can't speak for others. It's possible it didn't help.)

Comment: "Plot details of any scenes you remember
Descriptions of any characters or locations"  

Included in the question.  Made the film easily identifiable

Comment: @DukeZhou Answerability and recognizability and 'easy to identify' are *all the same things* in this case. ID is *not* judged by them but rather by the *effort* put into the question itself and its structure. If you can't see the difference between the Q you're referring to and the example I just linked, I really don't know how else to explain this.